# matlab: using a vector of unknowns in fsolve

Tags: matlab, function

I need to solve a system of nonlinear equations; in order to use **fsolve** , I have written an m-file containing my function "myfun". This function is called by the main m-file.

Both the system and the unknowns must be written using a "**for**" loop.

Example:

```
function F=myfun(x)
n=20;`
for j=1:n
    c1=sqrt(x(j)^2-3*x(j));
    c2=x(j)^(1/2);
F(j)=c1+c2;
end
```

My problem is that I have to preallocate memory for my vectors, both F and x, otherwise the solver considers numel(x)=1.
But if I declare

```
F=zeros(n,1);
x=zeros(n,1);
```

I have the following output:

```
No solution found.
fsolve stopped because the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient,
but the vector of function values is not near zero as measured by the
default value of the function tolerance.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop, just use

```
F = sqrt(x.^2-3*x) + x.^(1/2);
```

Then you also don't need to declare n, c1, c2.

Your error message also doens't sound like it's a problem with the allocation, but more with finding a solution to you fsolve problem.

Comment: Using it in `fsolve` requires it to be a function, so I would prefer an anonymous function `fun = @(x) sqrt(x.^2-3*x) + sqrt(x)`.

Comment: yes, the F should still be inside the function as in the OP. An anonymous function is a nice alternative.

Comment: Actually, the example I posted is not so appropriate; I have oversimplified the problem.
My code sounds like that more or less:

    F=myfun(x)
    
    for i=1:20

    j=4+i

    if i>2 && i<20

    F(j)=x(i)*(1-sqrt(x(i)))+x(i-2)*(1-sqrt(x(i-2)))+x(i+1)*(1-      sqrt(x(i+1)));

    elseif i==1

    F(j)=x(i)*(1-sqrt(x(i)))+x(i+1)*(1-sqrt(x(i+1)));

    elseif...

    end

    end

Comment: The above approaches translate your function into a scalar function: a single `x` is mapped on a single `y`, and a vector `x` is mapped on a vector `y` of same length. We perform this step because solving an equation or, equivalently, a function is only possible if that function has as input an `x` (could be a scalar, could be a vector) and a scalar(!) output `y`. Your function is not doing that, so this is what you should fix. From the above, it is still not clear what your scalar function should look like.

Comment: As I need to solve a nonlinear system, I have found that fsolve is the only command that enables me to do that. So my output would be a vector containing the values of the unknowns. My real problem is that, since I have to write the equations of the system, in each equation there are at least 3 unknowns, whose indices don't correspond to the one of the equation. How can I fix it?
Please don't consider my first example, it doesn't reflect the complexity of my problem.